# Reproduce `Temporary failure in name resolution`

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq, networkmanager

How can I reproduce manually the `Temporary failure in name resolution` error, when doing `ping google.com` in linux?

Probably, I can add a broken DNS server by my own and specify it in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

I need this for testing my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files
```

That is remove all traces of the `dns` service for the `hosts` case (a normal line is something more like `hosts:   files dns` but have a look at yours before changing it).

Then, if a name/IP is in `/etc/hosts` the name resolution works, if it is not, it does not work as the DNS is not consulted.